# Supporting /restricting android app only for normal resolution?

Tags: android

Say if I decided to support only normal 320X480 screen resolution for the first release of my app,

Will these lines, hide the app from the high and small resolution screens on android market ?

<***supports-screens android:smallScreens="false" 
     android:largeScreens="false" 
     android:resizeable="false" 
     android:normalScreens="true" 
     android:anyDensity="false">***

If not can some one point in the right direction as to how to make sure that the app is not visible or available for download for rest of the screens ?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If you only want to support 320x480 screen resolution, you can simply use Android 1.5 as your build target. This will force all devices to emulate HVGA if they don't have that as their native display.

Comment: Thanks for the reply.
I have tried that. But the problem is that android tries to scale the pixels to match the aspect ratio of the 800X480 screen so 320X480 is not exactly 320X480 but something in between. The images look OK but, this messes up my physics engine scaling and things go wacky. Any other thoughts ...

Answer (score 0):

The Android Documentation says this about android:normalScreens

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/supports-screens-element.html#normal

HVGA medium density screens, WQVGA low density screens, and WVGA high density screens are included in this group.

I do not believe there is a way to restrict your app to one specific screen resolution.